# excel and birthday format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, date

I am new to this. I do not have a screen shot for this one.
In the region I am located the birthdays are listed as: yy-mm-dd

I have: 720415 and want to convert it to: 72-04-15.

Will following work:
=DATEDIF(DATE(LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,3,2),MID(A1,5,2)),TODAY(),"y")

or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: what exactly you are looking for, since you asked a Number 720415 to convert into Date (yy-mm-dd) format ??

Comment: I was looking for the answer I got.

Comment: YES, I know and the answer 45 has inspired me to remind about the Basic issue, and I've also posted the SOLUTION is in shorter format and meeting you both resentments. First convert the Number into Date and last count the Age.

Comment: If dates are always 20th century then this would do it `=DATEDIF(TEXT(A1,"1900-00-00"),TODAY(),"y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this will work, but you need to make sure the quotes around the "Y" at the end are straight quotes, not fancy ones.

In the long run, it might be a good idea to change this strange date storage for birthdate and use real dates.

[image]

Comment: But OP asks "I have 720415 and want to convert it to: 72-04-15", and the DATEDIF formula produces 45,,?? OP has never mentioned that the AGE should be counted !!

Comment: @RajeshS, calm down. Sometimes you need to read between the lines. I confirmed that the formula works. The conversion is nested inside the formula, so that works, too.